# How to send mouseWheelEvent to SWF, loaded to QWebView

Tags: c++, qt, actionscript-3, flash, mouseevent

I have a program, written in C++, using Qt 5.5.1 (can't switch to another version), running under Windows (7 or 10, doesn't matter).

So I have some FlashWidget, subclassed from QWebView. It loads html file, parses it and replaces %1 with appropriate path to *.swf

```
<object 
    class="flashPlayer"
    width=90%
    height=100% 
    type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
    id="bridgemovie"
    data="%1"  >
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"/>
</object>
```

SWF file has event listeners on mouse events: mouse down, up and mouse wheel

```
    addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_WHEEL, zoom); //"zoom" is just some internal function
    addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDown1);
    addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseReleased);
```

**Problem**: Dragging and clicking works pretty well, but loaded SWF doesn't receive wheel events. I can't modify SWF code, only C++ and HTML parts. So, how I can natively pass mouseWheel event from JS (or, perhaps, QWebView, if allowed so) to the loaded SWF file?

**P.S.** I've tried loading SWF with QAxWidget, and wheelEvent is received, but there are some rendering problems, so I'm trying to repair solution with QWebView.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like a bug in QWebkit, because there is no such problem in newer versions and QWebEngine. Will try use QAxWidget instead.